# MDX - Running Sum over months limited to an interval

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I have a query that after some sweating and some swearing works

```
WITH
    MEMBER [Measures].[m_active] AS ([Measures].[CardCount], [Operation].[Code].[ACTIVATION])
    MEMBER [Measures].[m_inactive] AS ([Measures].[CardCount], [Operation].[Code].[DEACTIVATION])
    MEMBER [Measures].[p_active] AS 
    SUM(
        [Calendar.YMD].[2016].[January]:[Calendar.YMD].CurrentMember, 
        [Measures].[m_active]
    )
    MEMBER [Measures].[p_inactive] AS
    SUM(
        [Calendar.YMD].[2016].[January]:[Calendar.YMD].CurrentMember, 
        [Measures].[m_inactive]
    )
    MEMBER [Measures].[tot_active] AS (
        SUM({[Calendar.YMD].[2010].Children}.Item(0):[Calendar.YMD].CurrentMember, [Measures].[m_active]) - 
        SUM({[Calendar.YMD].[2010].Children}.Item(0):[Calendar.YMD].CurrentMember, [Measures].[m_inactive])
    )
    MEMBER [Measures].[p_tot_active] AS 
    SUM(
        [Calendar.YMD].[2016].[January]:[Calendar.YMD].CurrentMember, 
        [Measures].[tot_active]
    )
SELECT
    {[Measures].[m_active], [Measures].[p_active], [Measures].[m_inactive], [Measures].[p_inactive], [Measures].[tot_active], [Measures].[p_tot_active]} ON COLUMNS,
    NonEmptyCrossJoin(
        {Descendants([Calendar.YMD].[2016].[January]:[Calendar.YMD].[2017].[August], [Calendar.YMD].[Month])},
        {Descendants([CardStatus.Description].[All CardStatus.Descriptions], [CardStatus.Description].[Description])}
    ) on ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

What I obtain is a table that for each months show the activation and deactivation relative to that month, the accumulated activations  relative to the period considered (starting from 1 January 2016 and ending 1 August 2017) and the total active cards from the beginning of time (january 2010) until the end time interval.

This interval is parametrized and the day are to be considered, with this query all the activations made in august are considered even the ones made after the 1st.

I try to make some modifications like this.

```
WITH
    MEMBER [Measures].[m_active] AS ([Measures].[CardCount], [Operation].[Code].[ACTIVATION])
    MEMBER [Measures].[m_inactive] AS ([Measures].[CardCount], [Operation].[Code].[DEACTIVATION])
    MEMBER [Measures].[p_active] AS 
    SUM(
        [Calendar.YMD].[2016].[January].[1]:[Calendar.YMD].CurrentMember, 
        [Measures].[m_active]
    )
    MEMBER [Measures].[p_inactive] AS
    SUM(
        [Calendar.YMD].[2016].[January].[1]:[Calendar.YMD].CurrentMember, 
        [Measures].[m_inactive]
    )
    MEMBER [Measures].[tot_active] AS (
        SUM({[Calendar.YMD].[2010].[January].Children}.Item(0):[Calendar.YMD].CurrentMember, [Measures].[m_active]) - 
        SUM({[Calendar.YMD].[2010].[January].Children}.Item(0):[Calendar.YMD].CurrentMember, [Measures].[m_inactive])
    )
    MEMBER [Measures].[p_tot_active] AS 
    SUM(
        [Calendar.YMD].[2016].[January].[1]:[Calendar.YMD].CurrentMember, 
        [Measures].[tot_active]
    )
SELECT
    {[Measures].[m_active], [Measures].[p_active], [Measures].[m_inactive], [Measures].[p_inactive], [Measures].[tot_active], [Measures].[p_tot_active]} ON COLUMNS,
    NonEmptyCrossJoin(
        {Descendants([Calendar.YMD].[2016].[January]:[Calendar.YMD].[2017].[August], [Calendar.YMD].[Month])},
        {Descendants([CardStatus.Description].[All CardStatus.Descriptions], [CardStatus.Description].[Description])}
    ) on ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

But I get this error on the relative fields:

```
#ERR: mondrian.olap.fun.MondrianEvaluationException: Members must belong to the same level
```

How can i solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Your CurrentMembers return the Month level since you are using the Day level in some calculations. It should be Month1:Month2 or Day1:Day2, not Day1:Month2.

Comment: Yes I understand this but how do I fix it? I still need the report detailed monthly but filtered from day1 to day2.

Comment: [Calendar.YMD].CurrentMember.FirstChild in order to convert the current month to the first day of the current month.

Comment: It sorts of works but it becomes to slow, I need to think it another way. Fist I had a WHERE statement with the date interval, it worked perfectly but then they wanted to add the total_active from the beginning of time and if I used the WHERE I was losing the data before the upper interval.